# The requested service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer' has not been registered

Tags: autofac

After updating to .net core 2.2 we have the following issue:

> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: 'The
>   requested service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer' has
>   not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a
>   component to provide the service, check for service registration using
>   IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an
>   optional dependency.'

We are using `preBuilder.Populate(services);`.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when following [Microsoft migration guide for migrating from Core 2.1 to 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

The problem might occur if you are **not** using *WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder* to create the default web host builder, and you change in the *CreateWebHostBuilder* method of the *Program* class to call *ConfigureKestrel* instead of *UseKestrel*, as suggested in the migration guide.

As far as I understand if you use *WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder* to create the default web host builder, it already calls *UseKestrel* which registers the *IServer* service. But you might get into some [conflicts](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/2760) if also using *UseIIS*, so to avoid this problems there is a new *ConfigureKestrel* call that does not register the *IServer*. So I think that if you are not using *WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder* then you still need to call *UseKestrel* or *UseIIS* explicitly.

Of course it might be something else that is causing the problems in your case, but I suspect that following the migration guide blindly (as I did) could cause problems for many developers out there.